# Best practice for Swift application color scheme implementation

Tags: swift, colors, themes

What is the best practice for implementing a color scheme for an iOS application?

My idea was to create a `ThemeUIViewController` that holds all the information (Tab bar Color, background color etc.) and make all other `UIViewController`inherit from it. Is this the correct way of doing this, or is there a better solution ?

Comment: Add an extension to UIColor and have different colors in that.

Comment: Extension from where? Each view needs to do that ? Can you please show an example ?

Comment: extension UIColor {
 
    class var look_AppThemeColor : UIColor {
        return #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    }
}

Comment: That needs to be done per UIViewController ?

Comment: No, In UIViewcontroller you just need to add  view.backgroundColor = UIColor.look_AppThemeColor

Comment: I am confused. In WHICH UIViewController? Is this solution should work with what I wrote - of having the ThemeUIViewController ?

Comment: In which Viewcontroller you want to change (Tab bar Color, background color etc.) there you directly access the UIColor.look_AppThemeColor.

Comment: If you need to change any color than change it in UIColor extension. You need not irerate through all the UIVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a UIColor extension and save your colors here.

```
extension UIColor {

    var yourColor: UIColor {
        //choose your custom rgb values
        return UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0)
    } 

    var yourSecondColor: UIColor {
        //choose your custom rgb values
        return UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0)
    } 
}
```

Then you can access them like any other UIColor:

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yourColor
navigationController?.navigationBar?.tintColor = UIColor.yourSecondColor
```

If you want to change navigation bar color or tab bar color you can write a UIViewController extension:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func setNavigationBarColor() {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.myColor

    }
}
```

And you can access the func in the viewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     self.setNavigationBarColor()
}
```

You can set the color of things like navigation and tab bars the same throughout the app via app delegate. Example:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.yourColor
    return true
}
```

Comment: Where should this extension be declared at ?
With this solution - I should define the background color for each UIVC, right ? What do you think about my idea of having a unified ThemeUIVC ?

Comment: You write an extension outside of class scope. Usually, you create a new file called extensions and add all your extensions there. Make sure you import UIKit. As for the unified ThemeVC, you could write a specific ViewController file and use the same file. I would recommend against it though.

Comment: Alright, I understand. I didn't know about the file with all extensions, so this is new :) But then if I want to change the theme, won't I have to iterate on all UIVC and change their backgroundColor = UIColor.newColor ?

Comment: Yes you wold have to go through each file and change. you can speed this up by creating a function in an extension and simply calling the function in the controller. see my changes above.

Comment: And what if I don't want to go through each and every UIVC? I want to change it ONCE and that it will be changed in my whole app

Comment: No, you need not change it in all the files. Instead change the color in UIColor extension

Comment: If you want to set it once and have it be the same throughout the app, you can set the colors in app delegate. see changes above